# will_paginate label 'showing from 1 to 10'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I need to show a label saying `Showing results from 1 to 10` and so as I'm moving between pages the next page will say `Showing results from 10 to 20` and so on.

Is this possible with `will_paginate` and if it's possible do you have any example code on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%= page_entries_info @posts %>` does the trick for you here. Check [this page](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/will_paginate/) out for example code.